# Is it possible to share ruby object with the dll that built with ruby.h?

Tags: ruby, windows, dll, exe

I have an executable that runs ruby code(RGSS3, precisely) and I also managed to build a DLL that included ruby.h and it's imported to the exe via LoadLibraryA.

I want to ask whether it is possible to share the object/memory between the exe and the dll? If yes, what should I do to make dll access the objects created by the exe and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Ruby objects are represented in C with `VALUE`, which is basically a pointer. It's a bit hacky to call those functions from RGSS3, though: you have to get the object's memory address (`object.object_id << 1`) and pass *that* to the function.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/gabteles/GARE) repository, specifically [this](https://github.com/gabteles/GARE/blob/master/teste.c) file. It declares ands exports a function you can use from RPG Maker importing it with `Win32API`. Supposing you compile the `test.c` from that repository into `test.dll`:

```rb
# Load RGSS3 dll
LoadLibrary = Win32API.new("kernel32", "LoadLibraryA", "p")
rgss3_dll = LoadLibrary.call("RGSS301.dll")

# Call function from your dll
bitmap = Bitmap.new(32, 32)

BitmapTest = Win32API.new("test.dll", "BitmapTest", "ll")
p BitmapTest.call(rgss3_dll, bitmap.object_id << 1)
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try it out later. It's very strange that the repo does not include any ruby header btw

Comment: sorry, it does not fully answer my question tho, when I call methods from ruby-c such as `rb_iv_set`, it ends with the error `rb_current_vm_ptr is nullptr` and crashes